# Selected option to empty value if there is no matching value in select option

Tags: jquery

I have select option :

```
<select>
    <option value="">Menu</option>
    <option value="11">Item 1</option>
    <option value="22">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

I have Jquery to change selected value :

```
var xval = '33';
$('select').val(xval);
```

How to make selected to Menu(empty value) if i have different value from select option?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking - could you possible elaborate / rephrase your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the value exists first:

```js
var xval = '33';
if ($(`select option[value='${xval}']`).length) {
  $('select').val(xval);
} else {
  $('select').val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">Menu</option>
    <option value="11">Item 1</option>
    <option value="22">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the `length` of the `option` element with that `value` you want to set for the `select`. If the `option` with that value exist then it must have length greater than 0 (mostly one as the value for the option elements are unique in most cases). Then, you can select the `option` element with that value else select the default `option`

```js
var xval = '33';
var elem = $('select option[value="'+xval+'"]');
elem.length == 0 ? $('select').val('') : $('select').val(xval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">Menu</option>
    <option value="11">Item 1</option>
    <option value="22">Item 2</option>
</select>
```